# Rendered Preview window not accurate at all

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm having real issues lining up the rendered preview to my animated render and I was wondering if anyone has any ideas why? I'm 'projecting' a video onto the screen using a transparency and a spot light which looks great in the preview but turns to crap in the render. I'm also losing a lot of contrast and perhaps gaining some fireflies.

3 things that could be the issue is that I'm using a volumetric box for the light effect, I'm using depth of field and also motion blur but when I turn them off and on it doesn't fix it.

[image: This is how it should look] 
[image: This is how it renders]

Any help would be hugely appreciated. I'm pretty close to screenshotting the whole sequence at this point lol.

Comment: The file (minus the plugged in video Resizor>Drone>Spot>Cube>Trailer into Thumbnail [the video is the nodes]): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B31B18vkzFfyVFRLZW9lZEpjMVU

Comment: Unfortunately, the video is not included so it looks all white for me in render and preview.

Comment: Yeah that's true. Obviously the video is big but here is the frame to plug in https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B31B18vkzFfyaUpBQzdKMGI3VGM

Comment: Render and preview look pretty much the same for me. Maybe you had accidentally turned off something for the preview?
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8u4m4z9e42qg3v/preview.png?dl=0    https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfqk3d9wf30moww/render.png?dl=0